# Showing List<> members in ListBox, in WPF with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, caliburn.micro

I want to show some data from `List<>` in `ListBox` without code behind.

I tried to use binding through `ItemsSource` and `DisplayMemberPath` but it doesn't work.

Model:

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{FirstName} + {LastName}";
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ShellViewModel : Screen
{
    List<PersonModel> people = new List<PersonModel>();

    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        people.Add(new PersonModel { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Snow" });
        people.Add(new PersonModel { FirstName = "Cersei", LastName = "Lannister" });
        people.Add(new PersonModel { FirstName = "Bran", LastName = "Stark" });
    }
}
```

View (XAML):

```
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" 
           Content="Personal Data:" Margin="10"/>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding people}" DisplayMemberPath="FullName"/>
```

Where am I going wrong? I will be grateful for an answer.

Answer (score 3):

`people` must be a *public property* for you to be able to bind to it:

```
public List<PersonModel> people { get; } = new List<PersonModel>();
```

You also need to set the `DataContext` of the `ListBox`, or its parent `Window`/`UserControl`/etc., to an instance of the `ShellViewModel`
, unless you are using some framework that does this for you.

If you are using `Caliburn.Micro`, this should work:

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="people" DisplayMemberPath="FullName"/>
```

You may also want to change the name of the property to **P**eople to cope with the default C# naming convention.

Comment: Ya I am using Caliburn.Micro. This works, thanks very much